# Dependency inversion in Typescript generics

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to supply a generic to another generic, which then uses that generic to determine the return type - ala dependency inversion?

Pseudo code, illustrating what I'd like to do:

```js
type GetTypeA<T extends (arg: any)=>unknown> = ReturnType<T>
type GetTypeB<T extends (arg: any)=>unknown> = Parameters<T>[0]

type Usage<Getter extends GetTypeA | GetTypeB,T extends (arg: any)=>unknown> = { 
  getter: Getter<T>
}

type TypeA<T> = Usage<GetTypeA,T>
type TypeB<T> = Usage<GetTypeB,T>

type A = TypeA<(a: string)=>number> // { getter: number }
type B = TypeB<(a: string)=>number> // { getter: string }
```

Of course, one would not use dependency inversion to solve the problem in my simple pseudo-code - however for large and complex types it becomes useful, as one can reuse type code without repeating oneself.

Comment: TypeScript does not have direct support [higher kinded types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) so there's no way to refer to, say, `GetTypeA` without its type argument.  There are ways to simulate/emulate such higher kinded types, but these workarounds involve a lot of boilerplate and is probably not worth it.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, TypeScript currently does not have direct support for so-called *higher-[kinded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)) types* that abstract over generic types in the way that generic types abstract over specific types.  If you have a generic type like `type G<T> = {prop: T}`, you cannot refer to `G` in the abstract without immediately specifying `T`.  You can't pass just "`G`" into some super-generic type like `H<G>` where, say,  `type H<F<~>> = F<string>`.  There's a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) for such support.  For now, it's not part of the language, and who knows when or if it will ever be.

In that issue some workarounds are mentioned in which you can simulate or emulate higher kinded types, but they require boilerplate that involves "registering" your generic types in advance.  For example:

```
interface HKT<T = unknown> {
    GetTypeA: T extends (arg: any) => infer R ? R : never;
    GetTypeB: T extends (arg: infer A) => any ? A : never;
}    
type Apply<F extends keyof HKT<any>, T> = HKT<T>[F];
```

And then the analog of your example code looks like this:

```
type Usage<G extends keyof HKT, T> = { getter: Apply<G, T> }

type TypeA<T> = Usage<"GetTypeA", T>;
type TypeB<T> = Usage<"GetTypeB", T>;
type A = TypeA<(a: string) => number>; // type A = {  getter: number; }
type B = TypeB<(a: string) => number>; // type B = {  getter: string; }
```

This may or may not be worth it for your use case.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#code/PTAEDsFNIE1AXA9qARAJ0gcwJYGd6RoqiaRRrYDGuo24oAhjAG4PiWQBQdBaAZgw6gAEgGkAKgB5xoALygAruADW4RAHdwAPlABvTgEgA4pHjiAngAdIAQQBcoGZAAeBcDBoAKBmkwO25gCUcjp0fISgAEqgAPxRoA5QzIQA3IYmZlaQAEIOTq5kHqDevg5hETbBsjoBsaA2CRCQyWhpAL6cnPBZ9ZaWADbmkgBioC5uRcqQ5oh8IhKSAVoANI468mJS4loA2sMAumnd1qAAqrgMpJJGYwXuNFMzc5ur23J6JKa8DjZ9g9evHQdLo9CzWGzSdZnC5XFAZMG2FCAo6grLZSHvc6XSCSOGmBHZJFrFEnBryBEQ7wOfAUcCYKo6cAKAC2ACNCFoUqAQAgemSPp94N8ICz2a1QB1jpBQNl3gTJFTQDS6PSQiK2RyuTypTL3rpQILhcq6VyOkA)